# Geospatial library for .NET Core?

Tags: .net, .net-core, gis, geospatial, spatial

I am trying hard to find any geospatial library that supports .NET Core, however with no success so far. Do you have tips for any?

My requirements are:

- compute intersection of 2 geometries
- compute buffer of a polygon/polyline
- compute polygon area
- compute length of a polyline
- work with different coordinate systems

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that [Entity Framework Core itself](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/09/12/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-2-preview-2/) uses [NetTopologySuite](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/) to provide spatial support for the SQL Server, In-Memory and PostgreSQL providers, I'd say NetTopologySuite.

Typically, this question would be closed as out-of-scope. The question's requirements are fundamental and should be covered by *any* spatial library. I doubt many people had realized NTS existed though before the EF announcement.

Comment: Thanks for the tip for NetTopologySuite - quickly looked into that, so far it looks promising. I realize that the requirements I stated may seem fundamental for any geospatial library. I wanted to put them down to avoid comments like "geospatial library is kind of abstract, tell us what you want to achieve..."

Comment: @JanPalas `geospatial library` isn't abstact. The requirements are fundamental *but* until recently there were no good OSS spatial libraries for .NET. There were paid libraries or libraries that explicitly targeted ArcGIS and ESRI.

Comment: Agree, for me it is not an abstract term at all. (...and that you mentioned ESRI: Yes, I am looking for a replacement for Esri.ArcGISRuntime library which does not support .NET Core) I am going to accept your answer after a bit more digging into NetTopologySuite.